# rust function with optional closure as parameter

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function that take a closure as an optional parameter.
I've tried the following code. Can you please help me to fix the last call 'test(None);' that does not compile ?

```
fn test<F>(opt_param: Option<F>)
where
    F: FnMut(String) -> bool,
{
    match opt_param {
        Some(mut opt) => {
            opt(String::from("hello"));
        }
        None => println!("hi"),
    }
}

fn caller() {
    let f = |data: String| -> bool { true };
    test(Some(f));
    test(None);
}
```

compiler says

```
note: required by a bound in `test`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
12 | fn test<F>(opt_param: Option<F>)
   |    ---- required by a bound in this function
13 | where
14 |     F: FnMut(String) -> bool,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `test`
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
27 |     test::<F>(None);
   |         +++++
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Rust is unable to tell what kind of function you're sending in when you don't send one at all. `None` by itself is insufficient. Maybe you need a `type` declaration to help with expressing the "correct" `None`? Then you could do `MyFnType::None`.

Comment: `test::<fn(String) -> bool>(None)` should work but is also a mouthful. Optional parameters of a generic type typically don't work very well in Rust because the generic needs to be specified even in the `None` case.

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem described by the compiler but struggled to write (I'm a true beginner in rust).
Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example how you can do that, if I understand correctly your question and what you are trying to achieve:

```rust
fn test<F>(opt_param: Option<F>)
where
    F: FnMut(String) -> bool,
{
    match opt_param {
        Some(mut opt) => {
            opt(String::from("hello"));
        }
        None => println!("hi"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = |data: String| -> bool {
        println!("{}", data);

        data.len() % 2 == 0
    };

    test(Some(f));

    test::<fn(String) -> bool>(None);
}
```

It should print `Hello` and then `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

It's [generally discouraged](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/type-safety.html#arguments-convey-meaning-through-types-not-bool-or-option-c-custom-type) to accept `Option` parameters in Rust, so even without the compile error, you should consider an alternative. This is especially true of parameters that expect closures, since most invocations of such functions will already be monomorphized into separate functions, so the caller should be in charge of runtime data like `Option`.

If the function does two completely different things, then you should have two different functions. This is just as easy to use with one-off calls like your example, and any actual options you have can be branched on in the caller.

```rust
pub fn test() {
    println!("hi");
}

pub fn test_with<F>(param: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(String) -> bool,
{
    param(String::from("hello"));
}

fn caller() {
    let f = Some(|_data: String| -> bool { true });
    if let Some(f) = f {
        test_with(f);
    } else {
        test();
    }
}
```

If the function substitutes an alternative closure when passed `None`, then it should take a closure unconditionally and let the caller pass the alternative.

```rust
pub fn default(_: String) -> bool {
    println!("hi");
    true
}

pub fn test<F>(param: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(String) -> bool,
{
    param(String::from("hello"));
}

fn caller() {
    let f = Some(|_data: String| -> bool { true });
    if let Some(f) = f {
        test(f);
    } else {
        test(default);
    }
}
```

If you must accept an `Option`, then there are various ways to avoid writing out a type for `None`.

```rust
fn caller() {
    let f = Some(|_data: String| -> bool { true });
    let none = None;
    
    // 1. use a closure
    let unifier = |_| {}; // a closure can only accept one type
    unifier(f);
    unifier(none);

    // 2. use an array
    [&none, &f]; // array values are all the same type

    // 3. use a binding
    let mut _binding = &f; // bindings can only have one type
    _binding = &none;

    test(f);
    test(none);
}
```

If the `Option` is actually bound to external runtime data, then this happens automatically.

Comment: Thank you.
I fully agree, if the function has a totally different ehavior in each case, as many distinct functions should be implemented. My original use case is about providing optional filtering feature to a function that build a vector. Building each element to add to the vector is costly since some of the data I need to build these objects involve nework. I don't need those data from network to decide if I want to filter the object.

Answer (score -2):

Just found a solution:

```
fn test<F>(opt_param: Option<F>)
where
    F: FnMut(String) -> bool,
{
    match opt_param {
        Some(mut opt) => {
            opt(String::from("hello"));
        }
        None => println!("hi"),
    }
}

fn caller<T>()
where
    T: FnMut(String) -> bool,
{
    let f = |data: String| -> bool { true };
    test(Some(f));
    let p: Option<T> = None;
    test(p);
}
```

Comment: Now what about the caller of `caller`? You're just kicking the can down the road; now the caller has to specify a type that is ultimately inconsequential.